# Cant Reach the angular method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys for some reason my code below dosent work and gives me this result. And when i click the save button, nothing alerts in the window? I think somehow im not reaching the angular library but im not sure. Help would be appreciated! Thankyou!

[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:20px">
<div>
    <label>Employee Name</label>
    <input type = "text" id="employeeName" ng-model="employeeName"><br />

    <label>Emploee Age</label>
    <input type = "text" id="employeeAge" ng-model="employeeAge"><br />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click = "saveEmployee()">
      Save <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
    </button>

  </div>

  <div>
      Emplyee Name: {{employeeName}}<br />
      Employee Age: {{employeeAge}}
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
function employeeCtrl($scope){
  $scope.employeeName = ""
  $scope.employeeAge = 0;
  $scope.saveEmployee = function(){
    alert('You have saved ' + $scope.employeeName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried calling the function but it still dosent work...

Comment: You must add ng-app and ng-controller in your html

Comment: already tried that... Didnt work

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qdoaX-iWC4

Comment: Why isnt it working :(

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? It seems like you are including it twice

Comment: The 1,2.6  angular version

Comment: Deleted all exept bootstrap and angular still no work :((((

Comment: your code has both angular 1.4.8 and angular 1.2.6 at the same time.  this is going to create script issues.  On top of that, you are using a deprecated syntax for your controller declaration.

Comment: also, you show loading angular.route 1.4.2, but don't really show using it.  If you *do* use angular.route, it will only work if it's version matches the angular version you are using **exactly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ng-app and ng-controller, this should work

```
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="employeeCtrl" style="margin:20px">
  <div>
    <label>Employee Name</label>
    <input type = "text" id="employeeName" ng-model="employeeName"><br />

    <label>Emploee Age</label>
    <input type = "text" id="employeeAge" ng-model="employeeAge"><br />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click = "saveEmployee()">
      Save <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
     </button>

</div>

  <div>
      Emplyee Name: {{employeeName}}<br />
      Employee Age: {{employeeAge}}
  </div>
</body>
```